# Laravel does not recognize the PHP class of Blade components

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I develop my Laravel applications using Windows with Laravel Homestead. In Laravel Homestead I am using PHP 8.0.21 and Laravel 9.23.

I deployed my project to a host without any errors. However, Laravel does not recognize the PHP class of Blade components, making it impossible to use the application.

It is as if the component were anonymous. I put a dd('hi') in the class construct and nothing happens.

I cleared all Laravel caches using artisan optimize:clear. I cleared all server caches. I checked access permissions. Nothing solved, still not being able to use the application.

In my local environment the application works, but in hosting it doesn't. I don't know what else to check as there is no error log.

The hosting PHP version is 8.0.20, I don't believe that's the reason for the problem.

Can you help me?

Component call

```
<x-admin.sidebar.sidebar-main />
```

Component

```
<div>
    The only way to do great work is to love what you do. - Steve Jobs
</div>
```

Class Component

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\admin\sidebar;

use App\Models\Menu;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class SidebarMain extends Component
{
    /**
     * Menus da área administrativa.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public array $menus;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        dd('xxxxxxxxxxx');
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.admin.sidebar.sidebar-main');
    }
}
```

Comment: assuming you are using them correctly, try composer-dumpautoload

Comment: Please show your component and blade code

Comment: @workservice I run `php artisan clear-compiled composer dump-autoload php artisan optimize` and didn't work...

Comment: @parth ok, done!

Comment: Also show your service provider code and also check that file name casing are correct, add that also

Comment: @parth sorry but I did not understand, wich service provider?

Comment: @Jader, where did you register the component

Comment: @parth but I didn't register any components, I create them by running artisan make:component, I don't change anything in the default structure

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I know it is caused by creating the component class file with its name in lowercase. I renamed the class and the filename and then ran `composer dump-autoload` with no luck. As a workaround, I renamed the blade file to anything else and modified the `render()` method and it worked, but I don't like this solution